# How to wait for a process to terminate (and also wait for the corresponding child processes) in PHP?

Tags: php, process, child-process

I have a program that normally run till it terminates, but under some situations, it created two children process, and the main process then exits. The children processes will be still running after the main process exited.

I want to call this program in PHP.

Originally, I used the following strategy (not valid php code),

```
$process=proc_open("python xxx.py");
while (1) {
   sleep(5);
   $status = proc_get_status($process);
   if (!$status['running']) {
       exit_loop;
   }
   if (timeout) {
      proc_terminate($process, 9);
      exit_loop;
   }
}
```

But then I soon found the  bug that the process actually exited immediately that $status['running'] is false, but the children process is still running. How to actually wait for all children processes?

2nd question is i haven't looked into the proc_terminate, but I also observed that proc_terminate may not work as I expected. Is that because the $process is a bash but not the real python process? It may also because that what I terminated is only the parent main process but not the children process.

Anyone advise me that whether the above code is robust PHP code or not? Is there any better way to deal with this?

Thanks.

======================

More info,

1. I run this program in shell (CLI), and not related to CGI functions. So I won't need to worry about max_execution_time.
2. I want to wait the children processes created by the main process opened by proc_open, I will only create one process in the program.
3. The python program I want to call may hang for very long time, so I want to check timeout and terminate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proc_get_status can get pid of child process

```
$status = proc_get_status($process);
$pid = $status["pid"]
```

then you can use `pcntl_waitpid` to wait until the child process exit

```
pcntl_waitpid($pid, $child_status);
```

But you need to have your php compiled with `pcntl` extension.

See [PCNTL Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php)

**UPDATE:** If you want to kill child process after a timeout

First: install a `SIGALARM` handler in your main process

```
function term_proc() {
   // terminate your all child process
}

pcntl_signal(SIGALARM, term_proc);
```

Second: use `pcntl_alarm` to send a alarm signal after seconds

```
pcntl_alarm($seconds)
```

For 2nd question, `proc_terminate` will work no matter what process be opend.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not intend to interact with the spawned process in some way (e.g. by redirecting its input or output), then you can use [`system`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) instead of `proc_open`. `system` will wait for the spawned process to finish, so there's no need to check on it every so often.

**Be careful:** Waiting on another process may result in your script being terminated due to exceeding the `max_execution_time`. It may also not play well with your web server's internal management of execution units.

**Update:** It seems that you want to launch a process X, then wait for all processes that process X itself launches to exit before continuing. I 'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but PHP is not intended for this type of work and what you are after is not possible to achieve with stock PHP. It would certainly be possible for a custom extension to be written in C that exposes this functionality, but as far as I know there is no such extension publicly available.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

I run this program in shell (CLI), and not related to CGI functions. So I won't need to worry about max_execution_time.

I want to wait the children process created by the main process opened by proc_open, I will only create one process in the program.

Lastly, The python program which uses some other program that may hang for very long time, so I want to check timeout and terminate it. System() may not terminate on timeout I think?

Comment: @user534498: Ah, I see. Updated the answer, but sadly what you want to do is not doable in PHP (at least without a custom PHP extension).

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult for a parent process to follow *all* of its descendants. A process will only be notified of direct child deaths. There's a few different mechanisms you can take that can try to do what you want, but best would be re-writing your application to not care about your process's grandchildren.

- `cgroups` provides enough mechanism for [`systemd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Features) to follow all the child processes started from a single initial `execve(2)` call.

  While you can use `cgroups` yourself, I haven't learned much about the consequences of trying to use `cgroups` for process management while `systemd` or `libvirt` or other tools might be doing similar things. (That's my ignorance more than a limitation of `cgroups` -- perhaps it handles it beautifully. I like to dream.)
- Open a `pipe(2)` in your process and give the read end of the `pipe(7)` created to the child process in a file descriptor high enough that it won't be used "accidentally". (`dup2(fd[0], 20)` is probably good.) *Make sure your other programs don't close unexpected file descriptors.* Set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on the writing end (`fd[1]`) using `fcntl(2)`'s `F_SETFL` command.

  Periodically try to write a byte into the pipe. Eventually, you'll either get `EPIPE` error returns indicating that the read end has been closed by all children OR you'll get an error return with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` meaning the pipe is *full* and there is still a child running.